# How to get all the tags and information in html page (specifically all the links in the page)?

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib

I'm trying to get all the links available on this page using BeautifulSoup.
But while fetching the URL with urllib and then parsing it with BeautifulSoup, i doesn't return all the information available on this page.

I have tried different parsers (html.parser,lxml, xml, html5lib), But it does not return me the desired result.

I know how to get tag details but the file in which I store the html data, does not contain the links available. But when I inspect element on chrome, it does show the links. Below is my code with the URL which I'm working on:

```
def fetch_html(fullurl,contextstring):
    print("Opening the file connection for " + fullurl)
    uh= urllib.request.urlopen(fullurl, context=contextstring)
    print("HTTP status",uh.getcode())
    html =uh.read() 
    bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    return bs
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
mainurl ='https://www.daad.de/deutschland/studienangebote/international-programmes/en/result/?q=&degree%5B%5D=2&lang%5B%5D=2&fos=3&crossFac=&cert=&admReq=&scholarshipLC=&scholarshipSC=&langDeAvailable=&langEnAvailable=&lvlEn%5B%5D=&cit%5B%5D=&tyi%5B%5D=&fee=&bgn%5B%5D=&dur%5B%5D=&sort=4&ins%5B%5D=&subjects%5B%5D=&limit=10&offset=&display=list'
a=(fetch_html(mainurl, ctx))
f= open("F:\Harsh docs\python\courselinks.py","w")
f.write(a.prettify())
f.close
```

For Result I'm interested in getting a link for "Embedded Systems (ESY)".

Comment: Just focus and elaborate on what you actually want. You main objective is getting lost within your numerous objectives.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the page you are scraping is rendering with javascript.
You can try using selenium and chrome. 
Or you can use the requests_html package https://html.python-requests.org/
to render the javascript before getting the html

Comment: I did not think about it. Thanks for the link!! I'm working on it. Will post a solution soon.

Answer (score 0):

Only to get all links from page use below code:(Python 3)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from urllib.request import urlopen

html_page = urlopen("http://www.google.com/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page)
for link in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^http://")}):
    print (link.get('href'))
```

Comment: "I know how to get tag details but the file in which I store the html data, does not contain the links available. "---My question is what if the HTML file does not have that data in first place. I did not know that javascript can be an issue. I'm working on it as Bendik explained